Storing clients card Django
I need to store customer loyalty cards.
It should be flexible. I have several variants of cards with different discount systems.
For example, the card by amount of purchases - > $100 - 5%, > $1000 - 10%, etc. Or by amount of visits - > 10 - 3%, 100 - 10%, etc.
Furthermore, it should store the different image for different types of cards and sales amount, for example 5% - silver colour, 10% - gold, etc.
I came up with the idea of storing in in database as JSON.
Visits for example:
schema = {1: {'discount': 5%, image: '....', 'style': {'background': ..., 'foreground': ...},
          2: {'discount': 10%, image: '....', 'style': {'background': ..., 'foreground': ...},
          3: {'discount': 15%, image: '....', 'style': {'background': ..., 'foreground': ...},
 }

class ABSCard(models.Model):
   title = field
   work_place = field
   ....

class Discount(models.Model):
   type = ....
   schema = JSONField
   abscard_id = ABSCard
   

But I'm not sure that storing JSON in PostgreSQL is the best way.

Suggestion: make your schemas object instantiations of a model
If I were you I would make the schema for the different types of discounts using Models, and then I would create actual objects in the database for the different discounts.
Here's how I would code the models:
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# enumerator for field in model below
class DISCOUNT_TYPES(models.IntegerChoices):
    VOLUME = 0, _("Volume")
    VISIT = 1, _("Visit")

# enumerator for field in model below
class STYLING_CLASSES(models.IntegerChoices):
    GOLD = 0, _("Gold")
    SILVER = 1, _("Silver")
    BRONZE = 2, _("Bronze")

class Discount(models.Model):
    discount_percentage = PositiveSmallIntegerField
    discount_type = PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DISCOUNT_TYPES, default=DISCOUNT_TYPES.VOLUME)
    amount_to_spend = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    num_visits = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    css_class = CharField(choices=STYLING_CLASSES, default=STYLING_CLASSES.BRONZE)

    # or instead of img URL you could do a FileField if you want to store the static image yourself
    img_url = URLField

class Card(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=60)

    # or if you want multiple discounts associated with a card, you could use a ManyToManyField here instead
    discount = ForeignKeyField(Discount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


Advantages of this method
Flexibility
This way you can associate one or more discounts (Discount model object) with any given Card model object. This gives you flexibility to customize later on. For example, you could then make a third model called UserLoyaltyCard that associates a Card object (the difference being the Card object is generic but the UserLoyaltyCard could have a User foreign-key field and an ID_number field, for example).
Styling
Notice how the Discount model above has a simple css_class field. This way, your CSS definitions will live in a static CSS file (or on your frontend if this is just a backend API), which is where styling should really be, not on your database.

Sorry, but I didn't get it. Okay, we have a Discount table. So, if I need 5 levels of discount, there should be 5 rows in Discount table? And, they should link to 1 row in the Card table. Also, half of the sales will be empty because I only use one type.

@Андрей, yes, you'd have 5 rows in the Discount table (and you would accordingly probably add another 2 options to the STYLING_CLASSES enumerator to have 5 total). And then yes, your Card table would have a ForeignKey field so that each Card object could link to one of the 5 discount tiers. Then, yes, you'd have another model for Sale objects, and this would link with a ForeignKey to either a Card object or a Discount object's ID (however you'd want to configure it). And you can make this discount or card ForeignKey field optional (Null=True, Blank=True) for sales that don't have a discount.
